# How to make Border around whole website

Tags: css, border

how can I add border around whole site, example like here: http://ksize.be/

and I want that border to stay on every page same static, only stuff inside it change when scrolling.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replicated the code in the example site:

```css
.ct, .cb, .cr, .cl {
    background-color: #e79d80;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.ct {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 12px;
}
.cr {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
}
.cb {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 12px;
}
.cl {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="ct"></div>
  <div class="cr"></div>
  <div class="cb"></div>
  <div class="cl"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you it does work awesome!!